# How to measure response times for sequence of server calls?

Tags: api, networking, performance-testing

Consider below scenario:

1. Client --> Call1 ---> Server
2. Client <--- Response1 <--- Server
3. Client processes the response and makes another call
4. Client --> Call2 ---> Server
5. Client <--- Response2 <--- Server
6. Client processes the response and makes another call
7. Client --> Call3 ---> Server
8. Client <--- Response3 <--- Server

For above scenario, which tools should I use to make the calls, process the response and measure the response time for the server calls.

Does SOASTA has this capability or any other tool?

What are the things I should keep in mind when doing this?

Comment: googled some online now. Runscope and Apigee Edge. Hope you will find them useful.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code changes, you can use [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com) to log and measure API calls. From the **Traffic Inspector**, click on **URL Builder**. Enter the URL of the API that you're calling, and you'll see a *Runscopified* URL below it. Any call that you make to the Runscopified URL will proxy through Runscope to the original destination URL.

In Traffic Inspector, you'll see the HTTP traffic appear, showing you the details of each request (request headers/body/params, response headers/body, status codes, **response times**, etc.) Again, no need to change any code -- just your request URL, and you'll have full visibility into your API traffic between your client and server.